# Problem involving P.D.F. containing an indicator variable

Tags: self-study, density-function, iid, indicator-function

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be independently and identically distributed random variables with probability density functions: $$f(x) = \alpha \;x^{-(\alpha+1)} \; I_{(x>1)}, \; \; \alpha > 0.$$

For which value of $\alpha$ is it true that **$\frac{1}{n} X_n$ almost surely tends to 0** ?

This is my working:

$$ \frac{X_n}{n} \rightarrow 0, \; \; \;\;\textrm{almost surely}$$
$$ \iff \text{ for any $\epsilon > 0$,   }P \bigg( \Bigg| \frac{X_n}{n} \Bigg| > \epsilon, \; \; \textrm{infinitely often} \bigg) =0 $$

So trying to Borel-Cantelli lemma:
$$ \sum_n P \bigg( \Bigg| \frac{X_n}{n} \Bigg| > \epsilon \bigg) = \sum_n P \bigg( X_n > n\epsilon \bigg)$$
$$ = \sum_n \bigg[ \int_{n\epsilon}^\infty \frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}\; dx \bigg] = \sum_n \bigg[ \alpha \; \frac{x^{(-\alpha - 1 + 1)}}{(-\alpha - 1 + 1)} \bigg]_{n\epsilon}^\infty \; \; \; \; (\textrm{if,} \; \; n\epsilon > 1)$$
$$ \sum_n \bigg[ - x^{-\alpha} \bigg]_{n\epsilon}^\infty = \sum_n \bigg[ \bigg( \frac{1}{n \epsilon} \bigg)^{\alpha} \bigg] < \infty$$
for $n_0 \alpha > 0$.

How do I proceed any further ?

Comment: try using the borel-cantelli lemma

Comment: This could benefit from the `self-study` tag and from reading [the wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) on how to ask homework related questions.

Comment: I have provided with my workings... can I be provided with hints with this question now ?

Comment: You're done if you can just remember which $\alpha$ that last sums converges for. Think convergence tests. Maybe add all that work as an answer...

Comment: Eh, one of the lower bounds on your integrals is $n \epsilon$... so be careful because evaluating stuff will depend on whether or not $ n \epsilon > 1$